# python use plotly to plot time series without date gaps

Tags: python, plotly

I am using python3. I have a price quote series of 1 minute frequency. The quote is only available in trading hours. I tried to plot it using plotly, but there are gaps in non trading hours and weekends. How can I make this plot consecutive?

My code is like

```
ifBasisPlot=go.Scatter( x=ifBasis.date, y=ifBasis.basis, line=go.Line(width=1,color='blue'), name='basis' )

data = go.Data([ifBasisPlot])

ifBasisPlot_url = py.plot(data, filename='ifBasisPlot', auto_open=False,)
```

the plot and the data is here: https://plot.ly/~shuaihou96/14/if/

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an open PR for the plotly project. [link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/99)

As mentioned in the PR, we could use a `tickformat` x axis attribute; @etpinard had made a proof of concept chart, but that may not work if zooming is involved.

Comment: do you know if there has been an update on this? I checked the link and the item seems close now but I didn't get exactly what the solution was...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this code

```
ifBasisPlot=go.Scatter( x=ifBasis.date, y=ifBasis.basis, line=go.Line(width=1,color='blue'), name='basis' )
```

into

```
ifBasisPlot=go.Scatter( x=range(len(ifBasis.date)), y=ifBasis.basis, line=go.Line(width=1,color='blue'), name='basis' )
```